# Change Title In Right-Click Menu of Taskbar Icon

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have searched for hours and cannot figure out how to set the title listed in this menu of a pinned executable that I am creating in VS 2015:

[image: Right-click menu of taskbar icon]

I assumed it is something you must set in the .rc resource file, but it is not tied to FileDescription, InternalName, OriginalFilename, or ProductName.

Does anyone know how to set it?

It seems to default to the name of the executable, but I know you can change it since some programs (like Steam and Chrome) have one that differs from the executable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an app is pinned to the Taskbar, its title is just the filename (minus the extension) of the shortcut to the app that is stored in the following folder:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

So, in your example, there would be a shortcut named `Google Chrome.lnk`.

Renaming a shortcut in that folder updates the displayed Title accordingly.  Unpinning an app from the Taskbar deletes its corresponding shortcut from that folder.

Comment: Hmm, I see the shortcuts there now. But something must control the name of the shortcut that is generated when you pin something. For example, if I drag "Steam.exe" to the taskbar and create the pin...the shortcut that is generated in that folder is titled "Steam Client Bootstrapper".

Comment: The initial name of the shortcut comes from the app's version resource (verified with my own apps, using the fields you ruled out in your question), or if there is no name present there, maybe the OS will be smart enough to use the `<description>` from the app's manifest if one is present (speculating).

Comment: I found if I change the data for the registry key C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe.FriendlyAppName in the registry location Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache then it will change the shortcut name on generation to whatever I set.

However, that only seems to work for Steam and not other executables...I guess something else is referencing that key to determine the name but only for Steam?

Comment: That is very odd that you say it comes from the fields I ruled out. I have all of that information set properly and it even shows when I look at the executable properties, but when I pin it then the link is still titled after the executable name instead.

Comment: As a test, I have an app that contains a version resource and a manifest with no description in it. When I run the app, whether I pin it or not, the title being displayed is the value in the version resource's `FileDescription` field.

Comment: Thank you so much! The issue was that there was a colon in the FileDescription field since the game has a colon in its name, which is not valid for the filename when it tried to generate the shortcut, so it was defaulting back to the executable name... >_>